Syntax error at or near "perform" on Recursive Query
I'm using a stored procedure to get the total query execution time in PgAdmin.
Based on some readings, I tried the following:
DO $proc$

DECLARE
  StartTime timestamptz;
  EndTime timestamptz;
  Delta double precision;
BEGIN
  StartTime := clock_timestamp();

    WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
        VALUES (1)
      UNION ALL
        PERFORM n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 3
    )
    PERFORM sum(n) FROM t;

  EndTime := clock_timestamp();
  Delta := 1000 * ( extract(epoch from EndTime) - extract(epoch from StartTime) );
  RAISE NOTICE 'Duration in millisecs=%', Delta;
END;
$proc$;

I was expecting to see something like this:
NOTICE: Duration in millisecs=0.106 DO    
Query returned successfully in 6 secs 898 msec.

Instead, I got this:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PERFORM"  LINE 13:   PERFORM n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 3
^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 189


Per the docs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-GENERAL-SQL

For WITH queries, use PERFORM and then place the query in parentheses. (In this case, the query can only return one row.) PL/pgSQL variables will be substituted into the query just as described above, and the plan is cached in the same way.

Therefore the query should be written:
DO $proc$

DECLARE
  StartTime timestamptz;
  EndTime timestamptz;
  Delta double precision;
BEGIN
  StartTime := clock_timestamp();

    PERFORM (WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
        VALUES (1)
      UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 3
    )
    SELECT sum(n) FROM t);

  EndTime := clock_timestamp();
  Delta := 1000 * ( extract(epoch from EndTime) - extract(epoch from StartTime) );
  RAISE NOTICE 'Duration in millisecs=%', Delta;
END;
$proc$;


Which when run yields:
NOTICE:  Duration in millisecs=0.138
DO

An alternative which captures the value of the CTE:
DO $proc$

DECLARE
  StartTime timestamptz;
  EndTime timestamptz;
  Delta double precision;
  sum_val integer;
BEGIN
  StartTime := clock_timestamp();

    WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
        VALUES (1)
      UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 3
    )
    SELECT sum(n) FROM t iNTO sum_val;

  EndTime := clock_timestamp();
  Delta := 1000 * ( extract(epoch from EndTime) - extract(epoch from StartTime) );
  RAISE NOTICE 'Sum is %', sum_val;
  RAISE NOTICE 'Duration in millisecs=%', Delta;
END;
$proc$;


This results in:
NOTICE:  Sum is 6
NOTICE:  Duration in millisecs=0.118
DO

